# Asp.net mvc editor templates Html.HiddenFor value is missing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I have created an editor template Named **UserRoles.cshtml** for my multiple select checkbox.

```
@model List<UserRoleView>

@{
    var context = Context.GetContainer().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();

    var avaliableRoles = context.Roles.Select(x =>
        new UserRoleView
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            IsInRole = false
        }).ToList();

    for (var i = 0; i < avaliableRoles.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(it => it[i].Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(it => it[i].Name)
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(it => it[i].IsInRole)
            </label>
        </div>
    }
}
```

I am generated my form in **Create.cshtml** with EditorForModel:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.EditorForModel()

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

And when I run the applicaiton my hidden values are missed. But checkbox has value.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you should be using the model in the view that is passed from the controller and not generating it in the view. You are mixing business logic with your presentation logic which is very bad practice. Your controller method should look something like this which also ensures that your DbContext instance is disposed after you use it.

```
public class AccountController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Create() {
        using(var context = Context.GetContainer().Get<ApplicationDbContext>())
        {
            var avaliableRoles = context.Roles.Select(x =>new UserRoleView
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
                IsInRole = false
            }).ToList();

            return View(avaliableRoles);
        }
    }
}
```

Your views should then look something like this.

**Create.cshtml**

```
@model List<UserRoleView>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.EditorForModel()

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**UserRoles.cshtml**

```
@model UserRoleView
@{
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name)
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsInRole)
            </label>
        </div>
}
```

Comment: he is using EditorTemplate.

Comment: @teovankot - updated method and the editor template.

Comment: @teovankot - you too. It always feels like a work in progress :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here:

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(it => it[i].Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(it => it[i].Name)
```

According to your code it should be:

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(it => avaliableRoles[i].Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(it => avaliableRoles[i].Name)
```

But if you are using EditorTemplates you don't need to create them for emumerations. It will work like this:

**Create.cshtml**

```
@model List<UserRoleView>


//This is actually should be in Controller like Igor mention
@{
    var context = Context.GetContainer().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
    //here you set your model
    Model = context.Roles.Select(x =>
        new UserRoleView
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            IsInRole = false
        }).ToList();
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.EditorForModel() //here you render collection. 

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**UserRoleView.cshtml** (*If you actually using EditorTemplates name should be same as your ViewModel name*)

```
@model UserRoleView

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name)
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsInRole)
   </label>
</div>
```

And **Razor understand that your model is collection** of `UserRoleView` and apply it to every item.

Comment: `UserRoleView.cshtml` - variable `it` should be `Model`